# Is a 150 watt LED suitable for a pendant fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, led, bulb

I want to replace a 150 watt incandescent bulb with a 150-200 watt LED bulb in my kitchen fixture which is a hanging 12-inch diameter fully enclosed glass ball. The guideline for the LED say it is not suitable for fully enclosed fixtures but one of the product details also stipulates the LED is suitable for use in a pendant fixture which is what this glass globe is.

The manufacturers info (manufactured by XMprimo) seems contradictory and I would like to know if this LED bulb is suitable for a 12" diam. glass globe fixture.

Comment: Many pendant style lights are not fully enclosed.  I don't see where the contradiction is.

Comment: You say this is a 150 - 200 Watt LED. Do you mean it will *replace* a 150 - 200 Watt incandescent? Have you already bought the LED or are you still shopping? What is the actual wattage on the LED? What is the lumens rating of the LED? Some LEDs are rated for hotter fixtures and some are not, but in general an LED will not take as high a temperature as an incandescent.

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer wisely states that their bulb should not be used in a fully enclosed fixture. (this is true of incandescents as well.) (it is always a bad idea to trap heat) However if you are replacing your old incandescent bulb with an LED you will need about 1/6 the wattage to produce the same lumens. (the actual brightness of light emitted). A 25-watt bulb LED will replace a 150-watt incandescent. Regarding the seeming contradiction you see in the lamp instructions; it is possible to have a globe type fixture that is vented.  They just don't want their bulbs in a non-vented globe fixture.  It shortens the life of the bulb.